# Are Wildlife Conservation Bond halal shariah complaint investments?

Tags: finance, investment

How is the Wildlife Conservation Bond generating money to pay out the dividends? Is it Shariah complaint?

Ref:
https://www.worldbank.org/en/news/press-release/2022/03/23/wildlife-conservation-bond-boosts-south-africa-s-efforts-to-protect-black-rhinos-and-support-local-communities

https://www.credit-suisse.com/about-us-news/en/articles/media-releases/rhino-bond-202203.html

Comment: Instead of linking webstites you should share the relevant quotes here in your question post!